# Instance variable placement?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I just have a small question regarding instance variable placements.

Example:

```
private void example_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    //do stuff
}
```

A mouse move event in c# polls all the time. Sometimes I might want to only run the code inside it when the mouse position fully moves to another pixel. So I would write this:

```
private void example_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if (_prevMousePosition == Cursor.Position) return;
    //Do stuff
}
```

My question is this: Does the variable "_prevMousePosition" go at the top of the class as per usual, or does it sit directly on top of the method, like so:

```
private Point _prevMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);
private void example_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    if (_prevMousePosition == Cursor.Position) return;
    //Do stuff
}
```

I feel like it should sit on top of the method since the only place it will be accessed is the event, and it's only purpose outside of the method is to retain the previous mouse position.

Also, if there's another way to achieve the same functionality without the instance variable, I'd love to know it.

Comment: It can go either place. Which do you prefer? I would suggest being consistent though. Most people would place it at the top along with other class variables.

Comment: You can put it wherever you prefer, unless you are working for someone with specific guidelines on this. I would personally put it on top of the method because it would be easier to find it, rather then having to scroll to the top of the code.

Comment: Note that if you find yourself wanting to 'scope' fields like this to associate them with particular methods, it might be an indication that an 'extract class' refactoring would be valuable.  Consider whether the methods and their associated helper fields logically belong together as a unit of responsibility that can be isolated from the overall responsibility of your main class.

Comment: The correct answer is: Yes and No.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is this: Does the variable "_prevMousePosition" go at the top of the class as per usual, or does it sit directly on top of the method, like so:

This is purely a personal preference.  The compiler does not care where you place it.  Placing it above the method is perfectly valid C#, and will not cause any issues.

The most standard conventions for C# code (including those enforced by tools such as [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)), would suggest that you place the field at the top of your class along with all other fields.  The advantage of this is that you can easily glance at your class and see all locally stored data, as well as make sure you properly initialize, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Be especially wary of having class fields that preserve state for a single method. Consider:

1. creating a separate class for handling mouse actions and preserving state (history)
2. giving your class a private instance of that separate class
3. subscribing some method on *that instance* to handle the `example.MouseMove` event
4. write handlers in your class that subscribe to higher-level events on *that instance* of your separate class

This will circumvent this problem of deciding where to put a heavily localized field.

---

For example:

```
class MouseTracker
{
    private Point _prevMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);
    //Maybe define some higher-level events here
    public event ... MouseMoveWithHistory;
    public void HandleMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_prevMousePosition == Cursor.Position) return;
        //Do stuff
        //Trigger higher level events
    }
}
```

Then, in your class:

```
private MouseTracker tracker = new MouseTracker();
...
//in your constructor
example.MouseMove += tracker.HandleMouseMove;
tracker.MouseMoveWithHistory += tracker_SomeLocalHandler;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you put it into the MouseMove event, you'll lose the value as soon as it goes out of scope. It should be placed at the class level.

Comment: Both examples have it at the class level; neither has it scoped within the method.

Answer (score -1):

**Not related to the core "Instance variable placement?" question**

"A mouse move event in c# polls all the time. Sometimes I might want to only run the code inside it when the mouse position fully moves to another pixel."

Huh?!...it doesn't fire for "partial pixels"...if these is such a thing.  It fires when you have a new position based on whole pixels.  It is possible to have the same position if you left the form and then re-entered at the same point, or maybe if focus switches and then returns and the cursor hasn't moved.  There may be other conditions when it's possible...but have you actually tested to see how often the new position matches the previous position?  I'm not sure what you're doing, but it doesn't happen very often on my system:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(example_MouseMove);
        listBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(example_MouseMove);
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _prevMousePosition = Cursor.Position;
    }

    private int counter = 0;
    private Point _prevMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);
    private void example_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_prevMousePosition == Cursor.Position)
        {
            counter++;
            listBox1.Items.Add(counter.ToString() + ": " + _prevMousePosition.ToString());
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            _prevMousePosition = Cursor.Position;
            this.Text = _prevMousePosition.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You know, I thought it fired per new pixel too, but it appeared I was mistaken.

Without the check for a new point, the code will continuously fire, slowing (read: freezing) the program whenever the mouse moved. With the check, it ran fine.

Comment: Something else is causing it to fire continuously; the MouseMove() event does not poll or fire for partial pixels...either you've got code causing it to fire continuously somehow, or something about your system setup isn't quite "right".

Comment: If the MouseMove() event really did fire continuously by default, it would cause apps to ramp up to 100% CPU usage simply by handling the event and not touching the mouse.  C# would have been laughed out of the development world in short order.  Try creating a **new, blank** project and simply place a `Console.WriteLine("hello?");` in the MouseMove() event to see if the problem persists there.

Comment: It wasn't fire continuously, but rather too many times during the movement. When the mouse was still, nothing happened. If I moved the mouse, the event fired.

Perhaps the code in the event was taking longer to finish than it was taking to fire another event, causing the hang...

Comment: One possible solution to that type of problem is to wait until the mouse has **stopped** moving for a certain amount of time before executing your code, but also allow it to be cancelled or paused if the mouse moves again before it completes.  Just depends on what you're doing...